# Displace toggle button in shiny

Tags: shiny

Can we display toggle button next to Iris title as shown below

[image]

Below is the code for this

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(DT)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$h3("Material switch examples"),
    
    materialSwitch(inputId = "switch1", label = "Night mode"),
    dataTableOutput("df")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
   output$df <- DT::renderDataTable({
     datatable(head(iris),caption = "Iris",options = list(dom = 'ft'))
   })
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `fluidRow` instead of the `caption` option:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(DT)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$h3("Material switch examples"),
    
    fluidRow(column(2,tags$h4("Iris")),column(10,materialSwitch(inputId = "switch1", label = "Night mode"))),
    dataTableOutput("df")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$df <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(head(iris),options = list(dom = 'ft'))
    })
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[image]